# Zend_Db_Select and N:N Relations

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have som trouble with Zend_Db_Select, its a long time ago since i have used it (-: I need
an result array like this:

```
USER 0
 ID -> 1
 MY_NUMBERS -> (array)
    -> 1 ONE
    -> 2 TWO

USER 1 (array)
 ID -> 2 (int)
 MY_NUMBERS -> (array)
    -> 1 ONE
    -> 2 TWO
    -> 3 THREE
    -> 10 TEN
```

This a part of my Query

```
$select->from(array('USERS' => $table))
    ->join(
        array('USERS_NUMBERS' => 'USERS_HAS_NUMBERS'), // many to many
        'USERS.ID = USERS_NUMBERS.USER_ID'
    )
   ->joinLeft(
        array('N' => 'NUMBERS'),
        'USERS_NUMBERS.NUMBER_ID = NUMBERS.ID', 
        array('MY_NUMBERS' => 'NUMBERS.NUMBER')
   );
```

But in the moment i get one record returned for each existing relationship, so if user 1 hast 5 Numbers i get 5 full records returned
for this user.

I know that my select is wrong in the moment to get the array like i  need it, but i have to idea how to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Zend_Db_Table and set up the relations in there, so your code is also more readable. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

Then when you have your user you can do something like:

```
$user->findDependentRowset('numbers');
```